# SQL command to update a field with a random but unique value from a list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following table structure

table: `Team`

```
+-------+-------------+----------+
|   id  |  companyid  | teamcolor|
+-------+-------------+----------+
|   1   |      1      |    null  |
|   2   |      2      |    null  |  
|   3   |      2      |    null  |   
|   4   |      2      |    null  |  
|   5   |      3      |    null  | 
|   6   |      4      |    null  |
+-------+-------------+----------+
```

List of available colors:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES('#f44336'), ('#E91E63'), ('#E91E63'), ('#9C27B0'), ('#673AB7'), ('#3F51B5'), ('#2196F3'), ('#03A9F4'), ('#00BCD4'), ('#009688'), ('#4CAF50'), ('#8BC34A'), ('#CDDC39'), ('#FFEB3B')) N(Colour)
```

I need an SQL update to initialize the `teamcolor` field of the `Team` table with a random color from the list of colors. The color must also be unique by `companyid`.

Desired outcome

```
+-------+-------------+----------+
|   id  |  companyid  | teamcolor|
+-------+-------------+----------+
|   1   |      1      | '#f44336'|
|   2   |      2      | '#E91E63'|  
|   3   |      2      | '#03A9F4'|   
|   4   |      2      | '#8BC34A'|  
|   5   |      3      | '#f44336'| 
|   6   |      4      | '#FFEB3B'|
+-------+-------------+----------+
```

What I've done already

```
UPDATE T
SET TeamColour = C.Colour
FROM Team T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Colour
    FROM (
        VALUES 
            ('#f44336')
            ,('#E91E63')
            ,('#E91E63')

            -- many rows
            -- ...
            -- many rows

            ,('#BF360C')
            ,('#3E2723')
            ,('#212121')
            ,('#263238')
        ) N(Colour)
    WHERE T.ID = T.ID
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    ) C
```

and

```
UPDATE T
SET TeamColour = C.Colour
FROM [Team] T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM [Team] T1
        ,(
            VALUES 
                ('#f44336')
                ,('#E91E63')
                ,('#E91E63')

                -- many rows
                -- ...
                -- many rows

                ,('#3E2723')
                ,('#212121')
                ,('#263238')
            ) N(Colour)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM [Team] T2
            WHERE T2.Company_ID = T1.Company_ID
                AND T2.TeamColour = Colour
            )
        AND T.ID = T1.ID
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    ) C
```

But this does not create unique instances of colors by `companyid` as required.

Comment: Are teams with same company id have the same colour?

Comment: @SerkanArslan no unique within the companyid

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is very close.
You just need to select several rows for each `companyid` rather than one.

The query below assumes that the list of available colors is long enough. It should have at least as many rows as the largest `companyid`. In the example below `companyid=2` has three teams, so the list of colors in `CTE_Colors` should have at least three rows.

`CTE_Colors` is just a list of all unique colors to choose from.

`CTE_Companies` is a list of all companies with the count of rows for each company. We will have to pick this number of random rows from the `CTE_Colors` for each company.

`CTE_CompanyColors` does just that. For each row in `CTE_Companies` it picks `CompanyCount` random rows from `CTE_Colors` using `CROSS APPLY`.
I use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)` function to generate a random 4-byte number. `NEWID` generates a GUID that looks like a random number. I prefer to use the function that does exactly what I need. The `ROW_NUMBER` assigns sequential numbers for the generated rows. These sequential numbers are partitioned by `companyid`, so the sequence restarts for each new `companyid`. This result has same number of rows as original `Team` table.

Now we need to join original `Team` table with the generated rows with colors. The `ROW_NUMBER` in `CTE_Team` generates sequential numbers partitioned by `companyid`, so that we could have something to join on.

`CTE_ToUpdate` joins original `Team` table with random colors and makes it ready for `UPDATE`.

Run the query below step-by-step, CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to understand what it does.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Team TABLE (id int, companyid int, teamcolor varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @Team(id, companyid, teamcolor) VALUES
( 1, 1, NULL),
( 2, 2, NULL),
( 3, 2, NULL),
( 4, 2, NULL),
( 5, 3, NULL),
( 6, 4, NULL);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_Colors
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES 
             ('#f44336')
            ,('#E91E63')
            ,('#E91FFF')
            ,('#9C27B0')
            ,('#673AB7')
            ,('#3F51B5')
            ,('#2196F3')
            ,('#03A9F4')
            ,('#00BCD4')
            ,('#009688')
            ,('#4CAF50')
            ,('#8BC34A')
            ,('#CDDC39')
            ,('#FFEB3B')
        ) N(Color)
)
,CTE_Companies
AS
(
    SELECT
        companyid
        ,COUNT(*) AS CompanyCount
    FROM @Team AS T
    GROUP BY companyid
)
,CTE_CompanyColors
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_Companies.companyid
        ,A.Color AS NewColor
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTE_Companies.companyid ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) AS rn
    FROM
        CTE_Companies
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP(CTE_Companies.CompanyCount)
                CTE_Colors.Color
            FROM CTE_Colors
            ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)
        ) AS A
)
,CTE_Team
AS
(
    SELECT
        T.id
        ,T.companyid
        ,T.teamcolor
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.companyid ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) AS rn
    FROM @Team AS T
)
,CTE_ToUpdate
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_Team.id
        ,CTE_Team.companyid
        ,CTE_Team.teamcolor
        ,CTE_CompanyColors.NewColor
    FROM
        CTE_CompanyColors
        INNER JOIN CTE_Team
            ON  CTE_Team.companyid = CTE_CompanyColors.companyid
            AND CTE_Team.rn = CTE_CompanyColors.rn
)
UPDATE CTE_ToUpdate
SET teamcolor = NewColor
;
```

**Result**

```
SELECT * FROM @Team;

+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | companyid | teamcolor |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 | #FFEB3B   |
|  2 |         2 | #E91E63   |
|  3 |         2 | #2196F3   |
|  4 |         2 | #673AB7   |
|  5 |         3 | #4CAF50   |
|  6 |         4 | #00BCD4   |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: can you explain step by step how this is working? Why CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)?

Comment: @domenicr, I added explanations to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @Team TABLE (id INT, companyid INT, teamcolor VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Team VALUES
(1 , 1 , null ),
(2 , 2 , null ),  
(3 , 2 , null ),   
(4 , 2 , null ),  
(5 , 3 , null ), 
(6 , 4 , null )



;WITH CTE_Team AS
(
    SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) RNK 
    FROM @Team
)
, RdnColor AS (
    SELECT N.*
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY NEWID()) ID  
    , COUNT(*) OVER() CNT
    FROM (VALUES('#f44336'), ('#E91E63'), ('#E91E64'), ('#9C27B0'), ('#673AB7'), ('#3F51B5'), ('#2196F3'), ('#03A9F4'), ('#00BCD4'), ('#009688'), ('#4CAF50'), ('#8BC34A'), ('#CDDC39'), ('#FFEB3B')
    ) N(Colour)
)
UPDATE T
SET teamcolor = C.Colour
FROM CTE_Team T 
INNER JOIN RdnColor C ON (T.RNK % C.CNT) + 1  = C.ID

select * from @Team
```

Result:

```
id          companyid   teamcolor
----------- ----------- ----------
1           1           #9C27B0
2           2           #00BCD4
3           2           #FFEB3B
4           2           #673AB7
5           3           #03A9F4
6           4           #CDDC39
```

Comment: The OP wants to have different colors for the `companyid`, not the same.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov it is not clear but I added two version of it

Comment: @SerkanArslan the Team table could potentially have more records than available colors. Your solution updates only 14 teams.

Comment: @SerkanArslan I get duplicate colors for companyid

Comment: @domenicr I tested the query and it updates the teams with unique colours for companyid.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TEAM(ID INTEGER,COLOR VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO TEAM VALUES(1,NULL);
INSERT INTO TEAM VALUES(2,NULL);
INSERT INTO TEAM VALUES(3,NULL);
INSERT INTO TEAM VALUES(4,NULL);

UPDATE TEAM 
SET COLOR=(
            with team as(
            SELECT ID,(RANDOM()*100)::INT RANDI FROM  TEAM
            ) 
            ,col as 
            (select 'violet' color,(RANDOM()*100)::INT RANDI union all
            select 'indigo',(RANDOM()*100)::INT RANDI union all
            select 'blue' ,(RANDOM()*100)::INT RANDI union all
            select 'green' ,(RANDOM()*100)::INT RANDI union all
            select 'yellow',(RANDOM()*100)::INT RANDI union all
            select 'orange',(RANDOM()*100)::INT RANDI union all
            select 'red',(RANDOM()*100)::INT RANDI
            )
            ,ASSIGN_COL AS (
            select id,col.color NEW_COLOR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY 
 ID) RN
            from team
            join col on MOD(TEAM.RANDI,2)=MOD(COL.RANDI,2)
            ) 
        SELECT new_color FROM assign_col where rn =1 and id=TEAM.id
        )
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `RANDOM` function and it doesn't allow `WITH` inside the query as you wrote. For what RDBMS did you write this code?

Comment: Ahh!! I wrote it for Redshift, but will work on Oracle with little modification.